# Edge native module not available in MAC OS

Tags: electron, edgejs

We are building an electron application with ASP NET CORE in which we used Electron Edge to establish connection to server side.

https://github.com/agracio/electron-edge-js

We could able to run application without any issues in Windows environment but when run **npm install** against MAC environment we are getting an error -  **Edge native module not available in not available at node_modules/electron-edge-js/build/Release/edge_coreclr.node**

Comment: We referred github-electron edge js issues list. Below was the exact issue we faced but none of the solution works

https://github.com/agracio/electron-edge-js/issues/102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the below github issue thread we confirmed that in MAC VS installs a special version of Mono runtime that is incorrectly detected by Edge.Js. It will not function on a Mac with VS.
https://github.com/agracio/electron-edge-js/issues/102